# How to test list of futures in Scala

Tags: scala, scalatest

I would like to test a method (using ScalaTest) that accepts a `List` of values and updates them in a database, returning a `Future` for each value indicating success of the update. Is there an idiomatic way to verify that all values are persisted in the DB?
How can I know when all `Future`s returned from the method are completed?

```
trait Result
case object A extends Result
case object B extends Result

def addToDB(i: String): Future[Result]

def persistUsers(users: List[String]): List[Future[Result]] = {
  users.map(addToDB)
}
```

I tried something like this (works) but is there a better way ?

```
"should update list " in {
  val users = List("a","b","c")

  persistUsers(users)

  Thread.sleep(1000)

  whenReady(db.find("a")) { result => result shouldEqual A }
  .
  .
  .

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you want to await for a list of Futures, you have several options (I don't know if ScalaTest has a whenReady for a list of Futures), one of them is using `Future.sequence(futureList)` to create a `Future[List[A]]`

```
val futures = persistUsers(users)

whenReady(Future.sequence(futures)){result => result shouldEqual users}
```

Comment: You need to use ScalaTest 2.0 and mixin the `ScalaFutures` trait for this to work.